# Why does the strong law of large numbers require random variables with the same variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

The strong law of large numbers states that for an infinite sequence of i.i.d random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$, and $\bar{X_n} = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$,

$$\bar{X_n} \rightarrow \mu \text{ for } n \rightarrow \infty$$

I can understand why there is the requirement for $\operatorname{E}[X_1] = \operatorname{E}[X_2] = \cdots = \mu$, and for them to be the same *type* of distribution (e.g. normal, exponential); but why is it important that they all have the same variance? If $n \rightarrow \infty$, why should it matter how large or small each variance is relative to each other? The variances should 'disappear' as we take the empirical average over $n \rightarrow \infty$, shouldn't they?

Comment: Try and imagine what is likely to happen if $X_n$ is Gaussian with zero mean and variance $e^{n^2}$.

Comment: There is a technical definition of when a sequence of independent random variables has "small enough" variances to support convergence. It's related to the Lideberg-Feller CLT (so not SLLN per se). For detailed discussion of SLLN see Terry Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks, I understand your counterexample! Do you want to post it as an answer to the question, so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't believe the requirement is for the RVs to have **the same** variance, just that the variance of each one of them is finite, i.e. that $Var[X_i] < \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance controls how likely and how much the variable is to be away from their mean. So the bounded variance is here to ensure that this deviation is controlled.

Indeed, ask yourself what is likely to happen if $X_n$ has variance $e^{n^2}$ (or any rapidly-growing sequence for that matter). Intuitively, there are going to be huger deviations at each step, without any chance of compensation.

To be more precise, let $M_n$ be the mean of the $n$ first terms. If $M_n$ converges, then $X_{n+1}=(n+1)M_{n+1}-nM_n=O(n+1)$ as, that is $X_n=O(n)$ as.

Of course, this cannot happen in the above example since $P(X_n \geq e^{n^2/2})$ is a positive constant.